# Can I get PatchCodeGUID with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, com

To get PatchCodeGUID I use the script :

```
$vbsCode = @"
Set msi = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set patchlist = msi.Patches("{786970C5-E6F6-4A41-B238-AE25D4B91EEA}")
For Each p In patchlist
    WScript.Echo p
Next
"@

$VBSFile = "$env:TEMP\temp.vbs"

$vbsCode | out-file -FilePath $VBSFile
$PatchList = cscript.exe $VBSFile | Where-Object {$_ -match "^{" }
$VBSFile | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$PatchList
```

Is it possible to get rid of of VBS and use Powershell only ?

P.S. {786970C5-E6F6-4A41-B238-AE25D4B91EEA} is RTMProductCodeGuid of SCOM agent

Answer (score 1):

You could use the third party module [Windows Installer PowerShell Module](http://psmsi.codeplex.com). It has the CmdLet `Get-MSIPatchInfo` which should give you the correct information (more info: http://psmsi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get-MSIPatchInfo.v2.3.0.0&referringTitle=Help.v2.3.0):

```
Get-MSIPatchInfo [[-ProductCode] <string[]>] [[-PatchCode] <string[]>] [-Filter <PatchStates>] [-UserContext <UserContexts>] [-UserSid <string>] [-Everyone] [<CommonParameters>]
```